# How to update the view in AngularJS when the data changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't seem to get this right: I've got an array with categories (objects) and a post object:

```
var categories = $http.get('/api/categories').success(function (data) {
    $scope.categories = data;
});

// The code below uses a Rails gem to transport data between the JS and Rails. 
$scope.post = gon.post;

// Suffice to say the $scope.post is an object like so:
...
_id: Object { $oid="54f4706f6364653c7cb60000"}
_slugs: ["first-post"]
author_id: Object { $oid="54ef30d063646514c1000000"}
category_ids: [Object, Object]
...
```

As you can see the post object has a property `category_ids` which is an array whit all categories associated with this post. In my view (haml) I have the following:

```
%label 
    %input{"type" => "checkbox", "ng-model" => "cat.add", "ng-change" => "addCategory(cat)", "ng-checked" => "currentCat(cat)"} {{cat.name}}
```

As you can see, the `ng-checked` fires the `currentCat()` function:

```
$scope.currentCat = function (cat) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cat.post_ids.length; i++){
        if (cat.post_ids[i].$oid == $scope.post._id.$oid) {
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

The function above loops through the categories in the post (the `category_ids` property of the post object) and compares it with the parameter given. It works fine with existing categories. The problem appears when I dynamically add a new category and push it in the categories array:

```
$scope.addCatBtn = function () {
    var category = $scope.cat;
    $http.post('/api/categories', category).success(function (data) {
        $scope.categories.push(data.category);
        $scope.cat = '';
        $scope.addCategory(data.category);
    });
};
```

The new category does not appear 'checked' in the view. What am I missing?
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**EDIT: Adding addCategory function:**

```
$scope.addCategory = function (cat) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i in $scope.post.category_ids) {
        if (cat._id.$oid === $scope.post.category_ids[i].$oid) {
            $scope.post.category_ids.splice(i, 1);   // splice, not slice
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {  // add only if it wasn't found
        $scope.post.category_ids.push(cat._id);
    }
    console.log($scope.post);
}
```

Comment: Whats the `addCategory` function look like?

Comment: have you tested that receive data following your post call? $http.post('/api/categories', category).success(function (data) {    console.log(data.category); // or sth like that

Comment: I've added the `addCategory` function

Comment: Yes, the `data.category` is fine and looks like the other categories, hence my conclusion that maybe the problem is the `currentCat` function is not firing when a new category is added to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngModel` and `ngChecked` are not meant to be used together.

You should be fine to just use `ngModel`.

Comment: how do I assign checked status in this case then?

Comment: Set the model value representing that field to true.